# How to combine the Facebook Likes both from my website and Facebook itself

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

When I post an article on MMAFight.com, it also goes to my Facebook pages so subscribers and friends can look at the latest posts. Sometimes someone "Likes" the article on Facebook, but it ONLY shows the "Like" on Facebook and NOT on my website. So there can be 5 people that liked my article on Facebook, but the Facebook button counter on my website shows "0".

On the other hand..

If someone "Likes" the article on my website, it will not show on Facebook. However, if 5 people liked it on my website, then my button counter shows "5", but nothing will be shown on my Facebook. Is there any way to combine the "Likes" so everyone knows how many people in TOTAL "Liked" the article?

So if there are 3 people who liked it on Facebook and 5 people liked it on my website, my button counter SHOULD show "8" in TOTAL.

I would also love for the comments to work that way as well, but not sure if you guys could support that as well.

Comment: Facebook api page for web sites has everything what you want. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ is it like this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Facebook Graph API for that.  That should give you the aggregated Likes.  The normal website like button depends on a URL which is supplied from your local web site.  The normal facebook like button is much the same but is limited to facebook.com URL's.  The graph API should allow you extract the total and display that instead.